# Unable to reduce the height of datagrid on window resize and column and row resize also not working,

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am using a Datagrid in a grid. The parent grid has gridsplitters and whole package is inside a page.

At runtime this page is rendered in a frame which is in a scrollviewer. Following are the major issue I am facing:

1. User unable to resize rows.columns despite setting CanUserResizeRows/Columns property to true.
2. When I try to reduce the gridsize beyond the number of visible rows, it doesn't happen.

Someone please reply.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<ScrollViewer  Name="scrollViewer1"  >
        <DataGrid CanUserResizeRows="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="name" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="rank" ></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```